# VueJS dynamic components with dynamic events

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

From an exernal source (for example api), I get a component definition:

```
{
    "component": "b-btn",
    "content": "Button",
    "attr": {
        "title": "Edit"
    },
    "events": {
        "click": "doSomething"
    }
}
```

This definition is used with a dynamic component:

```
<component :is="item.component" v-bind="item.attr">
    {{ item.content }}
</component>
```

and it works as expected (a vue-bootstrap button is shown, with the title 'Edit' and a button text 'Button').

Now I want to add events as well. Since VueJS 2.4 (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on), you can define events in object syntax like `<button v-on="{ mousedown: doThis, mouseup: doThat }"></button>`, I thought, just adding `v-on="item.events"` might work:

```
<component :is="item.component" v-bind="item.attr" v-on="item.events">
    {{ item.content }}
</component>
```

But it doesn't, since the value of the object property `click` is a string (`"doSomething"`) and not a callable.

```
// Just to make it clear
{"click": "doSomething"} != {"click": doSomething}
```

Is there any way to bind dynamic events (from JSON) to a component?

Comment: You could do `this["doSomething"]()`, but is "doSomething" already defined in the method's object of the Vue instance? Or where is it defined?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Yes, doSomething is definied on the vue instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to check programmatically, if a function with the given name exists in your component, and if so use that function instead of the string.
Therefore you need to manipulate your JSON.
I built a test case in CodeSandbox where I use a computed field which updates the `events` property by checking if a function exists with the given name for each key in the `events` object and replaces the value with the function.

Say my child component has an event `clicked` which fires upon clicking on a button.

My parent component looks like this:

```
data() {
return {
  item: {
    component: "TestComponent",
    content: "Button",
    attr: {
      title: "Edit"
    },
    events: {
      clicked: "alertText"
    }
  }
};
},
computed: {
  componentItem() {
    let item = this.item;
    if (item.hasOwnProperty("events")) {
      let events = item.events;
      for (let i in events) {
        if (events.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          let functionName = events[i];
          if (
            this.hasOwnProperty(functionName) &&
            typeof this[functionName] === "function"
          ) {
            // function exists
            item.events[i] = this[functionName];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return item;
  }
},

methods: {
  alertText() {
    console.log("I was clicked");
  }
}
```

See a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/oo9zj8qy9y

Comment: I waisted 6 hours of my time not thinking about such a simple solution. Thank you very much!